# Azure Data Studio: Settings for newly installed extensions not found/ don't appear in settings

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-studio

Trying to install new extensions in Azure Data Studio but settings not found for newly installed extensions.

[image: Installed Machine Learning extension, but settings are not found]

Same is case with any other extension. Given in the screenshot is version info, it is not latest but I don't think that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Studio version is not compatiable with the extension. Found it the hard way.

Comment: Can you add a source?

Comment: Instead extension worked with other versions like 1.31.1 & 1.32 without issues. Don't have source but that's how I know.